# Java casting order

Tags: java, casting, default

Let's say I have the following setup

```
class A {
    B foo();
}

class C extends B {

}

// later
A a = new A();
C theFoo = (C)a.foo();
```

We know `a.foo()` returns type B.

When I do `(C)a.foo()`, is it

1. Casting `a` to type `C` then attempting to call `foo()` on it?
2. Calling `foo()` on `a` and casting the result to type `C`?

I'm finding it difficult to determine, and have always just played on the side of caution with extra parenthesis (which isn't a bad idea, for readability, but now I'm curious)

This is in specific reference to `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` although I don't see how that would change the behavior.

Comment: A quick way to find out would be setting break points in the C.foo and B.foo and debug. Then whichever one is hit would answer your question. Great question by the way

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if Eclipse will let me set breakpoints in the Java core classes... :-)

Comment: You can do it on your own referenced libraries so I'd think core libraries react the same. As long as you have the source attached, it lets you set the breakpoints (haven't tested to see if they actually trigger)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`(C)a.foo()` is equivalent to `(C)(a.foo())`, i.e. #2 in the question.

To get #1, you would have to write `((C)a).foo()`.

The Java language specification does not specify operator precedence in a nice, easy-to-read summary.

[Appendix A](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/11precedence/) of *Introduction to Programming in Java* by Sedgewick and Wayne has a comprehensive table of operator precedence.

Appendix B of [The Java Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349806) has a table of operator precedence, but it is not as complete as Sedgewick's.

A close inspection of the [grammar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html) in the Java Language Specification can determine the relative precedences of the cast and method call expressions in question:

```
Expression:
        Expression1 [AssignmentOperator Expression1]]

Expression1:
        Expression2 [Expression1Rest]

Expression1Rest:
        ?   Expression   :   Expression1

Expression2 :
        Expression3 [Expression2Rest]

Expression2Rest:
        {InfixOp Expression3}
        Expression3 instanceof Type

Expression3:
        PrefixOp Expression3
        (   Expression | Type   )   Expression3
        Primary {Selector} {PostfixOp}

Primary:
        ParExpression
        NonWildcardTypeArguments (ExplicitGenericInvocationSuffix | this Arguments)
        this [Arguments]
        super SuperSuffix
        Literal
        new Creator
        Identifier { . Identifier }[ IdentifierSuffix]
        BasicType {[]} .class
        void.class
```

The relevant productions are bolded.  We can see that a cast expression matches the production `Expression3 : (Expression|Type) Expression3`.  The method call matches the production `Expression3 : Primary {Selector} {PostfixOp}` by means of the production `Primary:  Identifier {. Identifier }[IdentifierSuffix]`.  Putting this together, we see that the method call expression will be treated as a unit (an `Expression3`) to be acted upon by the cast.

Hmmm, the precedence chart is easier to follow... ;)

Comment: That seems to be consistent with the messages I'm getting from Eclipse. Are you aware of anything from the JLS that can support this? I wasn't able to find it (which I found surprising. I must have simply been using the wrong keywords with my Google-fu.)

Comment: @glowcoder: Consider studying the [grammar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html) specified in the Java Language Specification, in particular the definition of `Expression3`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of any pithy summary of operator precedence in an official Java publication.  As @Chris says, you would have to puzzle it out from the grammar.  Others have performed such an analysis, [Sedgewick and Wayne](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/11precedence/) for example.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the edit, it definitely "clears things up" (at least for those of us who are able to fuddle through grammars.) You know, for a group of folks who are so wrapped up in ensuring everything in the language is as easy to understand as possible, and in making things maintainable, it's surprising to see such poor choices for grammar element names. Imagine working with code where your variables were named in such a manner. (Okay we don't have to imagine, we've done it before, and we grumble about it when we do!)

Answer (score 5):

[Method call has a higher operator precedence than type casting](https://web.archive.org/web/20110716213410/www.uni-bonn.de/%7Emanfear/javaoperators.php), so `(C) a.foo()` will first call `a.foo()` and cast the result to type `C`.  In contrast, `((C) a).foo()` first casts `a` to type `C` and then calls its `foo()` method.