# What is the priority of casting in java?

Tags: java, casting

if I have a line of code that goes something like

```
int s = (double) t/2
```

Is it the same as

```
int s = (double) (t/2)
```

or

```
int s = ((double) t)/2
```

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762270/java-casting-order

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See [this table on operator precedence](https://web.archive.org/web/20110716213410/www.uni-bonn.de/%7Emanfear/javaoperators.php) to make things clearer. Simply put, a cast takes precedence over a division operation, so it would give the same output as

```
int s = ((double)t) / 2;
```

As [knoight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913784/knoight) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464036/what-is-the-priority-of-casting-in-java#comment35972524_23464058), this is not technically the same operation as it would be without the parentheses, since they have a priority as well. However, for the purposes of *this* example, it will offer the same result, and is for all intents and purposes equivalent.