# Math.pow() returning same result with different inputs

Tags: java

I have two empty arrays and some variables:

```
static int p = 41;
static int q = 67;
static int d = 83;
static int n = p * q;

static int[] encryptedBlocks = new int[charArray.length];
static int[] decryptedArray = new int[charArray.length];
```

the first of which is filled with the following (I've checked, and it is):

```
1573
1978
385
1092
1022
857
856
1387
225
606
2293
1339
1630
```

The second array I'm attempting to fill with the results of an equation in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < encryptedBlocks.length; i++) {
            int M = (int)Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n;
            decryptedArray[i] = M;
        }
```

Problem is I get the same result for `M` for each iteration.. I'm totally clueless as to what is going on:

```
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
2662
```

Just in case I've double checked `encryptedBlocks[i]` is indeed the next value each iteration, and it is.  Am I missing something in relation to using `int` and `Math.pow()`?

First two iteration values for `encryptedBlocks[i]`, `d` and `n`:

```
1573 83 2747 
1978 83 2747
```

Comment: What is `d` and what is `n`?

Comment: Oh, I apologise - edited question.

Comment: Looks like something might be overflowing, hence the constant result.

Comment: Show us sample values of `encryptedBlocks[i]`, `d`, and `n`.

Comment: @DYZ it's all in the question already.

Comment: 225^83 = 1.702742607×10¹⁹⁵

Comment: It is definitely an overflow, then.

Comment: You may have to change this `int M = (int)Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n;` with this `int M = (int)(Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n);`

Comment: Ah, overflow makes sense thanks guys.  @OusmaneMahyDiaw how about using long instead?

Comment: @xeon48 sure but i think KH.Taheri has just solved your problem

Comment: I guess you better implement modpow to prevent overflowing. Something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_modpow.htm

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw he did indeed, thank you very much Kh.Taheri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464058/3025545):

> a cast takes precedence over a division operation

Therefore, and as I mentioned in the comments, you have to replace this:

```
int M = (int)Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n;
```

With this:

```
int M = (int)(Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n);
```

Comment: This still won't produce correct answers. The output of the first operation shall be 13 according to this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1573%5E83)+mod+(41*67), but the code will produce different answer due to overflow

Comment: @IslamHassan 13 is the exact value I need..  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the code produce 13 for you? for me it's 1147 for the first value.

Comment: It produces 1147 in the code for me, I have been banging my head against the wall for days!  P.S. I did not know of the existence of wolframalpha... I wish I had..

Comment: The easiest way is to use BigInteger. Check my answer.

Comment: @IslamHassan; he just had a problem with the precedence. So, when he get larger values, he will, for sure, use a larger variables.

Comment: The values he's providing in the question will fail to be stored in int or even long. Precedence is not the only problem.

Comment: @IslamHassan you are mistaken! you can easily try it in your computer with `int` and it will work probably. If you still have an error, please, post your code somewhere and we'll give a hand.

Comment: As I commented, the problem is a wrong output. For the first number 1573, the output should be 13 as the link I posted says, however the above code will produce 1147. The code produces different outputs than what the op's mentioned, but still not the correct ones.

Comment: The code above will produce {1147, 2564, 1457, 2351, 2414, 982, 1073, 2480, 923, 1526, 704, 427, 235}, however the correct output is {13, 590, 570, 28, 301, 2068, 1720, 1379, 1891, 2018, 424, 2545, 25}

Answer (score 2):

In your line of code

```
int M = (int)Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n;
```

You are calculating Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d), then casting it to an int, then using modulo m on the int result. What you probably wanted to do was only cast to int after all the math was done:

```
int M = (int) (Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n);
```

which yields:

`1147
2564
1457
2351
2414
982
1073
2480
923
1526
704
427
235`

for the given input data.

Answer (score 1):

Just precedence mistake
  change this   `int M = (int)Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n;`                to 
`int M = (int)(Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are casting to int to early and that is causing the output to be same always. You can check this in the below output.

```
package test;

public class MathPow {

    static int p = 41;
    static int q = 67;
    static int d = 83;
    static int n = p * q;

    static int[] encryptedBlocks = {1573,
            1978,
            385,
            1092,
            1022,
            857,
            856,
            1387,
            225,
            606,
            2293,
            1339,
            1630};
    static int[] decryptedArray = new int[13];

    public static void main (String []args){

        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedBlocks.length; i++) {
            double power = Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d);
            System.out.println("Power : "+power);
            double pwer = power % n;
            int M = (int)pwer;
            decryptedArray[i] = M;
            System.out.println("M : "+M);
        }

    }

}
```

Output when the casting to int is done at the end.

```
Power : 2.1305119658955046E265
M : 1147
Power : 3.8617294369074443E273
M : 2564
Power : 3.9195891716526933E214
M : 1457
Power : 1.4875753889539146E252
M : 2351
Power : 6.087295034019223E249
M : 2414
Power : 2.7378409793777127E243
M : 982
Power : 2.4849775423187883E243
M : 1073
Power : 6.199351610800489E260
M : 2480
Power : 1.702742606656262E195
M : 923
Power : 8.815111415893474E230
M : 1526
Power : 8.194765730142982E278
M : 704
Power : 3.332636081546012E259
M : 427
Power : 4.0885674380373943E266
M : 235
```

And output when the casting is done just after the Math.pow operation.

```
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
Power : 2.147483647E9
M : 2662
```

You can see that the power operation result is same hence M is same as well.

Comment: Ah, very interesting regarding the power operation.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the power operation is too large to be stored in an integer. `1573 ^ 83` alone is a 122-digits number, and you're doing the mod operation after calculating the power, so it has already overflowed.

If performance is not a concern, you can use BigInteger class. This should work:

```
BigInteger bigN = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
for (int i = 0; i < encryptedBlocks.length; i++) {
    BigInteger M = BigInteger.valueOf(encryptedBlocks[i]).pow(d).mod( bigN );
    decryptedArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(M.toString());
}
for(int i : decryptedArray) System.out.println(i);
```

However, `BigInteger` operations are a bit slow. If you prefer a faster solution you can implement your own power function so you can do a mod operation whenever you're near to overflow an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the parentheses.  This is how the compiler sees what you wrote:

```
((int) Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d)) % n
```

It's subtle but what's happening it's casting to an `int` before taking the modulo.  Ordinarily, this wouldn't make a difference but in your case, `Math.pow` is returning such a large number that casting it to an `int` truncates it to `2147483647` the maximum value an int can store, then it takes the module of that which will return `2662`.

Now, to get the correct answer all we need to do is make sure it calculates the modulo first:

```
(int) (Math.pow(encryptedBlocks[i], d) % n)
```