# Why is my implementation of math.random in my class only returning 0?

Tags: java

I've been trying to create a class to roll dice for games, and my code for one aspect of it is:

```
public int[] yahtzeeRoll() {
    int[] rolls1 = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        rolls1[i] = ((int) Math.random()*6+1);
    }
    return rolls1;
}
```

yet, when I call it in the main method, it only returns 1 for each of the values. Why is this? How can I fix my code so that it generates 6 different numbers when I print the array in the main method?

Comment: Have you tried `(int)(Math.random()*6.0+1)`?

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the `double` value returned by `Math.random()` to `int` before multiplying by 6, and since `Math.random()` returns a value < 1, casting it to `int` results in `0`.

Change

```
rolls1[i] = ((int) Math.random()*6+1);
```

to

```
rolls1[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type casting by appending `(type)` takes precedence over the `* 6` bits afterwards. Therefore, the result from `Math.random()` is always casted into 0 before you multiply it by 6, which turns out to always be 0 as well.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464058/8557739) points to [this site](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php) which explains it quite well.

Either `(int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1` or `(int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1)` would work as you have intended.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random returns a floating point number between 0 and 1 but you are truncating it down to 0 by using (int) type cast before it. Use parentheses around your expression and then prepend (int) to that if you do wish to use integer truncation.

Btw, I think same sequence should be generated at each run if you don't seed the pseudo-random engine, say with current time or something.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns `double` value in range [0, 1) (greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0). Then you cast that `double` value to `int`, so it always results in 0. After that you add 1 to it, so the result always remains 1.

You should cast result of multiplication - `Math.random() * 6` instead of casting `Math.random()` return value:

```
rolls1[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
```

By the way, you should be aware of operators precedence in Java language. You can have a look here: [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) to see nice table that shows that casting has a higher priority than multiplication and addition - this is the reason, why `(Math.random()*6)` is put in parenthesis for casting (this way you avoid casting only `Math.random()`)

PS. There is also a link to [table of operator precedence in official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), but it doesn't exactly fit to your problem as it doesn't contain operation of casting - this is the reason, why I provided another link firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the expression.

```
((int) Math.random()*6+1)
```

Now `Math.random()` returns a `double` that is `>=0` and `<1`.

You then cast that result to an `int` which means it will always become `0`.

If you use.

```
(int)(Math.random()*6+1)
```

You are taking the `double` between `0` and `1`, multiplying it by `6` (giving `0 ... 6`) adding `1` and then casting to an `int`. This looks more like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a clue from the below output presentation which is self explanatory.
Code:

```
double random = Math.random();
System.out.println("Math.random()>>"+random);
System.out.println("Math.random()*6>>"+random*6);
System.out.println("(int)(Math.random()*6)>>"+(int)(random*6));
System.out.println("Math.random()*6+1>>"+random*6+1);   //+1 here is treated as a string by java and will add at the end of the number
System.out.println("(Math.random()*6+1)>>"+(random*6+1));   //number random*6 will be incremented by 1 as enclosing () will treat them as numbers
System.out.println("(int)(Math.random()*6+1)>>"+(int)(random*6+1));
```

Output:

```
Math.random()>>0.6793602796545469
Math.random()*6>>4.076161677927281
(int)(Math.random()*6)>>4
Math.random()*6+1>>4.0761616779272811
(Math.random()*6+1)>>5.076161677927281
(int)(Math.random()*6+1)>>5
```

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal 3.93... is a calculator answer and I agree. Java code only adds 1 to 2.9370739993590416 and returns 2.93707399935904161, check the 1 added at the end of the result.

Comment: It would act like you say if would take String representation of that value (e. g. String myString = String.valueOf(Math.random) + 1 - in that case  +1 means that you concatenate result with 1 at the end. When working with double +1 gives 3.93....

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal that is how exactly I have done. Sharing my code here FYR. double random = Math.random();System.out.println("Math.random()*6+1>>"+random*6+1);

Comment: Try this: double random = Math.random(); System.out.println("Math.random()*6+1>>" + (random*6+1)); <- this will make operation inside parenthesis perform as mathematical operation, not as String concatenation. Sorry for the previous comment - SO Android App changes quotes to strange texts when I'm editing my comment.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal you are right, ()s are doing all the difference, edited my answer accordingly. Thank you for highlighting this.+1 to you :)