# Type promotion in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with the below Java statements:

```
byte b = 10;
byte r = (byte) (b * b); // Giving correct result
byte r = (byte) b * b; // Giving error " POSSIBLE LOSS OF PRECISION"
```

Why is it mandatory to give parentheses to `b * b`?

Comment: `(byte) b * b` makes a `byte * int`, which will return an `int` that you then attempt to assign to a `byte`

Comment: Interestingly if you were doing `b *= b;`, that would compile as in that case the language specification requires an implicit casting to the original type.

Comment: @ernest_k I admit I haven't looked at the spec for a while, but does byte * byte always return an int?

Comment: @Powerlord It does indeed always produce an `int`. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) is the only spec I found for it. If you look at the [bytecode list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings), you'll also see that there are no instructions for arithmetic for `byte`s; so it has to use `imul`

Comment: @Powerlord Yes, `byte*byte` reurns `int`, that's why the second line needs a cast.

Comment: @Powerlord Yes, according to [jls8 §4.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) a multiplicative operator on an integral type will result in a value of either `int` or `long`. The same error like in the question will happen for multiplying `char` or `short` aswell

Comment: Might also be useful to check [What is the priority of casting in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464036/what-is-the-priority-of-casting-in-java)

Comment: Fun fact: making `b` `final` allows it to compile.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think that is because the constant folding allows to optimize and figure out that the result fits in a byte too, no need to widen to int.

Answer (score 25):

`(byte) b * b` casts the value of the first `b` to `byte` (*which is redundant since it was already `byte`*), and multiples it by the value of the second `b`. Multiplying two `byte`s  promotes them to `int` first, since there is no `*` operator for `byte`s. Therefore the result is `int`, and cannot be assigned to a `byte` variable.

On the other hand, `(byte)(b * b)` casts the `int` multiplication result to `byte`, which can be assigned to a `byte` variable.

This is covered in the JLS in [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int**.

Answer (score 6):

Casting problem

```
byte r = (byte) (b * b);
```

It casts the `(byte)` type to the result of `(b * b)`

```
byte r = (byte) b * b;
```

It casts the `(byte)` type to the first `b` only, therefore it will become `((byte) b) * b`

Answer (score 2):

By the precedence rule you are casting only the first b to byte instead of the whole result.

And Java follow some rules, as you can see [here](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-int-double-float-mixed-type-division-arithmetic-rules)

> All integer values (byte, short and int) in an arithmetic operations (`+`, `−`, `*`, `/`, `%`) are converted to `int` type before the arithmetic operation in performed. However, if one of the values in an arithmetic operation (`+`, `−`, `*`, `/`, `%`) is `long`, then all values are converted to `long` type before the arithmetic operation in performed.

So, by just casting the first `b` you are doing this:

```
byte = byte * integer
```

Hence:

```
byte = integer
```

Thus, raised error.

Answer (score 0):

Variables of type `byte` must be [-128,127], that is why the compiler must not accept any operation, `b*b;b+b;b-b;b/b` without a cast on the result of operation, like: `(byte)(b*b)`.

In the code below, when you change the result type to `int` it compiles.

```
 byte b=10;
    byte c=(byte)b*b;      //incompatible but correct when c is int
    byte d=((byte)b)*b;      //incompatible but correct when d is int
    byte r=(byte)(b*b); 
    byte t= b*b;             //incompatible but correct when t is int
    byte e=(byte)b/b;      //incompatible but correct when e is int
    byte f=((byte)b)/b;      //incompatible but correct when f is int
    byte o=(byte)(b/b); 
    byte w=b/b;             //incompatible but correct when w is int
    byte g=(byte)b+b;      //incompatible but correct when g is int
    byte p=((byte)b)+b;      //incompatible but correct when p is int
    byte q=(byte)(b+b);
    byte x=b+b;             //incompatible but correct when x is int
    byte h=(byte)b-b;      //incompatible but correct when h is int
    byte v=((byte)b)-b;      //incompatible but correct when v is int
    byte s=(byte)(b-b);
    byte y=b-b;               //incompatible but correct when y is int
    byte k=(byte)b;
    byte u=b;
```

**NOTE**

As @andy Truner pointed out in comments, when `b` is `final`, all the previous instructions compile!!, except for the following set up:

```
   final byte fn=-120;
    byte z=fn-b;               //this does not compile even when both final, because the result would be -130, out of the byte type interval!!
```