# Java Type Casting gives compilation error within System.out.println call

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, runtime

In the code below the first line gives a compilation error (symbol not found for the getAttributeMethod). The second line works as expected. Do system.out.println calls get picked up by the compiler and is type casting resolved after compilation? This doesn't seem to be the case so I don't really understand what is happening in this scenario.

```
System.out.println((Element) ev.getTarget().getAttribute("id"));
Element temp = (Element) ev.getTarget();
System.out.println(temp.getAttribute("id"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java casting order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5762270/5221149).

Comment: Operator precedence matters. `.` takes precedence over casting.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast it like this:

```
System.out.println(((Element) ev.getTarget()).getAttribute("id"));
```

If you are not casting the return Element of getTarget (which I assume is Object) the Compiler is looking for the function "getAttribute" in the class Object, but cannot find it and therefore gives a compiler error.

Comment: Correct answer, but an explanation of why this is needed would make it a better answer.

Comment: Updated it for more explanation

Comment: Close, but it’s not that the compiler is looking for a getAttribute method in Object, it’s that the compiler is looking for a getAttribute method in [EventTarget](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/EventTarget.html), since that is the return type of [ev.getTarget()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/Event.html#getTarget--).