# Java: Type cast before clone?

Tags: java, clone

Edit: I encounter this problem when I need to clone a object, and I've searched but no question solve my problem.

When I was learning the prototype pattern in  Java, I followed some tutorials and get confused about the type-casting of `(Bike)super.clone()`.

Which is done first? `(Bike)super` or `super.clone()`? Why `(Bike)` is needed?

```
public interface Prototype extends Cloneable
{
    public Prototype clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
}

public class Bike implements Prototype
{
    // Constructor and other methods...

    // My question is here
    public Prototype clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Bike)super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java casting order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762270/java-casting-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast has lower priority than function calls:

```
(Foo) a.f1().f2().f3() // Casts to Foo at the end of the calls chain
```

In your case the cast is necessary because you're calling `super.clone()`, which is a method inherited from [`Object.clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) which returns an `Object`

Comment: I give vote to you because I found a space between `(Foo)` and `a`, which helps me remember the point.

Answer (score 2):

The class `super.clone()` executes first, then the result is cast using `(Bike)` (casts are applied to the result of the expression that follows).

You need the cast because you are overriding [`Object#clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()), which dates back to pre-generics JDK1.0 and has a return type of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Prototype is the super class of bike, when the super.clone() is called, a cloned object is returned which is then Explicitly typecasted into a more specific subclass of Prototype, which is Bike.

The type casting is needed to suit the requirements of the Bike class.
A more general view is that every object created has Object class as its super class but also has user defined methods which were not defined in to super class(Object class). Once you type cast it into the child class, you can access the parent methods and the child methods from the same object