# calling method or casting(priority)?

Tags: java, object, compilation, compare

I don't know what the problem is with the following code? In **IntelliJ**, at compile-time, an error occurs to the compareTo method and says that this method does not exist in the Number class.

```
Number x = new Integer(3);
System.out.println(x.intValue());
System.out.println((Integer)x.compareTo(new Integer(4)));
```

Doesn't it convert to an Integer object first and then the method is called?

Comment: No, it does not - method invocation comes first - check  [Java casting order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5762270/15244370) on this very site

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't it convert to an Integer object first and then the method is called?

No, it converts the *result* of the method to `Integer`. You'd need to call `((Integer)x).compareTo(new Integer(4))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are trying to compare a number to an integer and then cast the result to integer. It is always preferred to use brackets to help the reading, or even better use the built in functions to get the variable in the desirable way